# Gradle dependency error after upgrading to Android Studio 3

Tags: android, facebook, gradle

I have just upgraded Android Studio to the latest version. With the new version a new gradle version is being used and several changes have been made to gradle as well. I have followed the guides to update my gradle file and all errors are gone except the following one:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preFreeDebugBuild'.

> Android dependency 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads' has different version for the compile (10.0.1) and runtime (11.0.4) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution

I have checked and made sure that only version 11.0.4 is used in my gradle file (google ads, analytics etc). The problem seems to arise from using the Facebook ads SDK - I have checked the latest integration guide on AdMob and I am using the latest Facebook SDK, i.e.,

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.26.0'
implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:4.26.0.0'
```

If I remove the above statements the project compiles with no problems. If I include the facebook sdk I get the error above so I am thinking that the Facebook SDK is using version 10.0.1 of Google ads and that is why the problem is happening.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue today after updating to Android Studio 2.3.

I had to update my build tools to 25.0.0 you can do this by changing the buildToolsVersion and changing the `compileSdkVersion` to 25 in the `build.gradle` file in your main module.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I upgrade Android Studio to 3.0 but keep gradle plugins version at `2.3.0`. This will keep all your dependencies with `compile`, no need to change to `implementation`.

Comment: I thought that Android Studio 3.0 does not work with Gradle versions earlier than the latest one

Comment: @user501223 No, AS 3.0 allow you to work with previous version of Gradle. It's only recommended us to upgrade.